# A locally compact space having a non-locally-compact open subset

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for an example of the thing in the title. So far I tried many topologies but none seemed to work.

Thoughts: I obviously have to find some non-Hausdorff space because otherwise the example doesn't exist. I thought of some non-Hausdorff spaces in which the compacts are easy to detect, but then I found that all the open sets in them are in fact locally compact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289521/closed-subspaces-of-a-locally-compact-space-are-locally-compact

Comment: @AshwinIyengar that's very relieving! I'll change my question to "open" instead of "closed".

Comment: What is your definition of "locally compact"?

Comment: @DanielFischer each point has a local base consisting of compact sets.

Comment: Then every open subspace of a locally compact space is locally compact. For each $x \in O$, there is a compact neighbourhood (in $X$) of $x$ contained in $O$, since the compact neighbourhoods form a local base.

Comment: If your definition were "each point has a (quasi)compact neighbourhood", there'd be examples.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't understand how your argument proves that $O$ is locally compact. You have to show that for each open subset $U$ of $O$, there exists a compact neighborhood of $x$ in $O$ which is contained in $U$.

Comment: If $O$ is open, then every $O$-neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ is also an $X$-neighbourhood of $x$, so by the local compactness of $X$, there is a compact $X$-neighbourhood $V$ contained in $U$. But $V$ is of course also an $O$-neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer got it.. thanks